# C pointers and arrays

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, while-loop

In this code I have a function besides main which finds a specific character in a string (sentence) and returns a pointer to it and otherwise it returns NULL:

```
char *position (char letter, char *sentence){
int i=0;
while (*(sentence+i) != '\0') {
    if (toupper(*(sentence+i)) == toupper (letter))
      return (sentence+i);
    ++i;
}
return NULL;}
```

It's all clear to me here.

And in  the main function i have to use the previous function (position) to find how many times does a specific letter appear in a specific sentence.

```
int main (void){
char sentence [200+1];
char letter;
char *pos = sentence;
int counter=0;
gets(sentence);
scanf("%c", &letter);
while (pos != NULL){
    pos = position (letter, pos);
    if (pos != NULL){
        ++counter;
        pos +=1;
    }
}
return 0;   
}
```

What is unclear to me is what is exactly in the pos variable once it is set and how exactly the while loop at the end works?

edit: forgot to initialise variable `i` in `function()`, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: You didn't initialize `i` in `position()`.

Comment: `pos` is incremented by pointer arithmetic. Is the current position in the string.

Comment: Don't use `gets()` use `fgets()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets do a small example: you've got the String "abaab" and your looking for the Letter b. As you know a C-String always ends with '\0'. So at beginning your pos represents the whole string.

```
abaab\0 //pos represents ="abaab"
| 
pos
```

After that you call your function: postiton(pos, 'b'). Pos now points on the seccond letter. And with this pos only represents the smaller String "baab".

```
abaab\0 //pos represents="baab"
 | 
pos
```

After ++pos; you got this situation: (pos represents a smaller String)

```
abaab\0 //pos represents ="aab"
  | 
 pos
```

When you now call the position function again. pos will point on the next 'b'. And of course the String is shorter again.

```
abaab\0 //pos represents ="b"
    | 
   pos
```

Increment pos:

```
abaab\0 //pos represents =""
     | 
    pos
```

Calling the position function again will return NULL, because there is no 'b'. When this function returns NULL the while function is finished.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and helpful reply, I get it now!

Answer (score 1):

> What is unclear to me is what is exactly in the pos variable once it is set and how exactly the while loop at the end works?

Your code contains lot of bugs but if your question is just what I quote a simple answer is:

`pos` is a pointer in `sentence` string. Start to point in where `sentence` point and move away to reach the end of string.

`position()` take a start point end return the point where `letter` is found, otherwise it return `NULL`: so when you write `pos = position (letter, pos);` `pos` is moved to `letter` position. After that by `pos +=1;` you move away to the next element (move the pointer of one char).
When there are any letter `position()` return `NULL` and `while` cycle terminate.

Answer (score 0):

pos is initialized with `char *pos = sentence;` which lets it point to the first character in `sentence`, due to arrays "decaying" to pointers in most expressions, like this one. After that, it points to elements inside `sentence` because `position()` returns `sentence+i` which is the address of the first element of sentence plus the offset i.